# Duplicate inactive sheet and Rename based in active cell data

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a working sheet, "Booking Form".
I have a template of the working sheet, "Exported".

What I would like to do in this function is;

- duplicate template sheet "Exported".
- rename duplicate sheet "Copy of Exported" by data in cell C:7 from working sheet "Booking Form".
- then copy data from sheet "Booking Form" into the newly duplicated and renamed sheet.

Making sense?

Here's my work.

Debugger is stopping at duplicate active.
I'm not at all great at Google sheets.
I have limited understanding of the scripting.
I just pick up bits and pieces by googling other examples.

```
function EXPORT() {



  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();

  var is = ss.getSheetByName("Exported");

  var as = ss.getSheetByName("Booking Confirmation");

  var title = as.getRange('C7').getValue();

  is.duplicateActiveSheet();

  is.renameActiveSheet(title);

  var source = as.getRange ('A5:C23');

  var dest = is.getRange('A5:C23');

  source.copyTo (dest, {contentsOnly: true});

  

}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it.

```
function EXPORT() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sti = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
    var sta = ss.getSheetByName('Booking Confirmation');
    var ti = sta.getRange('C7').getValue();

    sti.copyTo(ss).setName(ti);

    var stc = ss.getSheetByName(ti);
    var source = sta.getRange('A5:C23');
    var dest = stc.getRange('A5:C23');

    source.copyTo (dest, {contentsOnly: true});

}​
```